# Filter OUT traffic with a specific query variable

Tags: google-analytics

I want to have Google analytics ignore all traffic that comes with a specific query parameter, ?mysearch=1

I am using that query parameter from an internal tool that I cannot change nor can I have the tool use a specific user agent, it's an ancient monitoring tool that I am being mandated to use.

It will always hit the site at a few different specific URLs, e.g. https://example.com/?mysearch=1 or https://example.com/about/?mysearch=1 or https://example.com/team/?mysearch=1

There will never be a time that real traffic will have the ?mysearch=1 query variable.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use a segment when you see your Analytics data that exclude all users that contains `page` with `?mysearch=1`. So you can see report without these users.